# IntelliJ - Change Editor Highlight Line where Cursor is Located

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ 14, and I haven't found a way how I can change the color of the line highlight in the editor, where the cursor is located.
Also, searched the net, didn't find anything useful.

Look how awful it looks with my customized color scheme.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change that in *Editor/Colors and Fonts/General*. The exact entry you must change is *Caret row* (which is perhaps the reason you could not find it because everyone would expect this to be named something like line highlight :)).

Comment: Thanks, you are right about hard searching for it :)